# Regex Junit Test

Tags: java, regex, junit

I am working on a Junit test that is supposed to test the number of occurrences of words that DO NOT contain the vowels (aeiou).

```
String matchString = "^[.[^aeioAEIO]]*$";
```

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: No, it really isn't the right regexp, for lots of reasons.  But why do you need a regexp in your JUnit test?  A JUnit test should supply definite input to the unit under test, and assert that definite output has happened.  I can't see the application of a regexp.

Comment: Im learning Regex and I am testing with a .txt file and I'm looking for the number of occurrences of strings without vowels. Can you explain how I can go about to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to match all the words that do not contain your vowels is:

```
String matchString = "\\b[^\\saeioAEIO]+\\b";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]+\b
```

This will match any word that consists only of ASCII consonants.  Don't forget to double the backslashes if you're using this as a String literal.

Comment: +1. That's probably safer than my answer but it all depends on exect requirements.